# How to set icon packs programmatically

Tags: android, icons, launcher

Is it possible to set launcher icons programmatically?

There are many Icon packs available but is it possible to create my icon pack and to set it programmatically from my code?

Answer (score 1):

It depend on the Laucher. You should contact the developer of the Launcher to get some documentation.

Not all the launcher will be compatible, BTW.

For instance, here is a guide for APex Launcher, my personal favorite: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1649891

I think it is also compatible with Nova and some other popularone.

Answer (score 0):

I dig this for 3 weeks, even I posted question too [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670299/change-default-system-application-icon/18695314#18695314) but not much attention I got!

Yes its possible to develop your own icon pack, even I created one of but for the compatibility you have to contact to `launcher` provider. What I tried I download [ADW Launcher](https://github.com/AnderWeb/android_packages_apps_Launcher) and [Icon pack](https://github.com/Wysie/ADW.Tagture) and I succeed.

Here I'm listing couple of things which I got while doing R&D.

[Thread 1#](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2291008)

[Thread 2#](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2399426)

[Thread 3#](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1822505)

[Thread 4#](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1649891)